# QImage display sharp pixels

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have a matrix with boolean values that I'm trying to plot with QImage. I have imported the image from a uchar vector with 0 and 255 values for false and true respectively. I would like to have black and white squares representing the different values, but instead I get blur between the pixels as shown in [the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ROP.png). Could you please let me know how to get rid of the blur and display larger pixels?

The code is as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<world.size(); ++i) {
    if(world[i] == true) 
        world_uchar[i] = 255;
    else 
        world_uchar[i] = 0;
}

QImage img(world_uchar, cols, rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

QLabel myLabel;
myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
myLabel.setScaledContents(true);
myLabel.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setScaledContents` I draw a resized image every times that the window size changes, or on the image change. See an example below (on that example I've used `QMainWindow`):

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
private:
    QPixmap pixmap;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    //SetMinminumSize to ensure that the QLabel
    //can be resized
    ui->label->setMinimumSize(10, 10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QBitArray world(256, false);
    uchar *world_uchar = new uchar[world.size()];
    int cols, rows;
    cols = rows = (int)qSqrt(world.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i += 2)
        world.setBit(i, (qrand() % ((1 + 1) - 0) + 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < world.size(); i++)
    {
        if (world[i])
            world_uchar[i] = 255;
        else
            world_uchar[i] = 0;
    }

    QImage img(world_uchar, cols, rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    OnResize();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    OnResize();
}

void MainWindow::OnResize()
{
    if (!pixmap.isNull())
        ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(ui->label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
}
```